# Is it possible to integrate bootlint on VisualStudio 2017?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2017

Since ESLint and CSSLint now come integrated on VisualStudio (showing warnings and erros on the IDE), is it possible to make it use bootlint (probably through node.js)?

If not, what's the proper way to validate a C# MVC project (it's Views) on BootLint?

Comment: [first result with google](https://scottaddie.com/2015/09/09/improve-asp-net-mvc-6-view-quality-with-bootlint/)

Comment: Yes, of course I found that. But, it's targeted primarily to Visual Studio Code and has some instructions on Visual Studio 2015 - both for ASP.Net Core projects and using Node.JS and Gulp. Not at all an integration to the IDE (like the ones mentioned above - ESLint and CSSLint).